# ADAL Login and authenticate user depend on Microsoft account login/logout

Tags: angularjs, adal

We are trying to do silent SSO in my application. We use adal-angular.js library for user sign in. The scenario is, If user sign in office 365 account, and open my application, user doesn't have to login in our application. but if user sign in office 365 and our application token expire after 1 hour user logout unexpectedly. Don't know how to handle this. We require that user should depend on office 365 or Microsoft account login/logout.

Answer (score 1):

If user have an active session with Azure AD, ADAL JS does get renew token after token expire automatically (unexpected logout will not happen). ADAL JS examines the projected expiration of the existing token (in the cache) and if the token is about to expire, it uses an invisible iFrame to send a new token (renewal) request to Azure AD.

This is discussed in detail [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/) (with sample code) by Vittorio and the mechanics of silent renewal is discussed [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/).

Comment: ADAL JS does get renew token after token expire automatically, is not happen in adal.js latest version, I have test it. I handle this by manually calling adal.Login() method after token expiry, but this also generate new problem. After expiry of token if adal.login() method is called, user is again get new token and authenticate user.